# How do I find all questions containing certain text and the user is from a certain country?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, data-explorer

I am trying to build the following query:
Find all questions containing certain text and the user is from a certain country.

What I have done so far is:

```
SELECT     q.Id AS [Post Link],
           q.Score,
           q.Tags,
           q.Creationdate
FROM       Posts a
INNER JOIN Posts q
ON         q.Id = a.ParentId
WHERE      LOWER(q.Body) LIKE N'%' + LOWER('SearchTerm') + '%'
```

This kind of works good, but I couldn't figure out how to add the filter for the user who is asking the initial question is from a certain country. I know there is a Location query, but how do I combine these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To filter on questions only, the join to `Posts a` works, but it's easier to filter on `PostTypeId = 1`.
- You do need to join (on Posts.OwnerUserId) to get information about the user.
- To make reusing your query easier, consider using [parameters](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#parameters).
- Searching questions like this could easily lead to timeouts because of the large volume of data.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1113061/search-for-questions-by-query-and-user-location) is an updated version of your query.

If you didn't already view it, give the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) a try. There's also a [chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) where you might be able to get help with SEDE.